# Python Regex for selecting text between fixed title

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to get the text between two fixed header in python.
Please check this link http://regex101.com/r/jV4oP5/1
I want to extract everything that starts after **OPINION** . The regex I wrote matches only first Line as well as **OPINION BY**. 
Is there any other regex that can fetch the data.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: How about showing some example what to match and what not to match? How many lines after 'OPINION' do you want to match? Certainly not the entire document...

Comment: Everything after OPINION and 2 of ** Documents.

Comment: Problem with your regex is that it matches only one block of newlines, then one block of other stuff. Try flag `re.DOTALL` or repeated groups of newlines and other stuff. Also remember to add some end marker and to use non-greedy matching. Something like `OPINION(.*?)\d+ of \d+ DOCUMENTS` with flags `gs`, though that does not find the last one due to the missing terminator.

Comment: Actually My problem is to select all text after OPINION till text 2 of ** DOCUMENTS is reached then OPINION of 2nd doc to beginning of 3rd and so on. I hope you are getting what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dotall modifier(`s`) to extract everything after OPINION.

```
OPINION.*
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/jV4oP5/3)

If you don't want to match `OPINION` then use a lookbehind,

```
(?<=OPINION).*
```

Comment: `.*` excludes new line characters

Comment: @SamP did you see the demo?

Comment: Ah you put a modifier on it, my bad. Comment retracted.

Comment: Actually My problem is to select all text after OPINION till text 2 of ** DOCUMENTS is reached then OPINION of 2nd doc to beginning of 3rd and so on. I hope you are getting what I mean.

Comment: Where is text 2 of DOCUMENTS?

Comment: @SarvagyaPant i got it. see http://regex101.com/r/jV4oP5/4 . letme know is that works or not?

Comment: Well the regex matches two documents, but leaves the third document ie 3 of 92. There is Opinion too. I tried every combination but still failing

Comment: But the last opinion wasn't ended with DOCUMENT. sO the regex engine isn't matches it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean you want the entire document after "OPINION", try: `(OPINION(\n*.*)*$)`

Your regex was only finding the first new line character followed by any normal characters (excluding new line).